# Modelsim Testbench not generating console output

Tags: verilog, modelsim, quartus

I've designed a unit for my homework here,

```
module homework1(a, b, sel, y);

input signed [7:0] a, b;
input [1:0] sel;
output reg signed [7:0] y;

always @(a or b or sel) begin
    case (sel)
        2'b00: y = a + b;
        2'b01: y = a - b;
        2'b10: y = (a > b) ? a : b;
        2'b11: y = (a > b) ? b : a;
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

I've designed a pretty simple testbench file to run with Modelsim here,

```
module testbench();

reg signed [7:0] a, b;
reg [1:0] sel;
wire signed [7:0] y;

homework1 target(a, b, sel, y);

initial begin
    $display("Hello!");
    $monitor($time, "a = %d, b = %d, sel = %b, y = %d", a, b, sel, y);
    #10 sel = 0; a = 32; b = 25;
     #10 a = 46; b = 0;
     #10 a = 18; b = 52;
     #10 a = 37; b = 37;
     #10 a = 37; b = 37;
     #10 $stop;
end

endmodule
```

I used Modelsim to run the test bench, and while the waveform came out as expected, but not the text output. Any ideas?

It seems to work in older version of Modelsim. I'm using 10.3d now. Any settings that might cause this?

[image: modelsim]

Answer (score 1):

Try running your simulations with the `-displaymsgmode both` optional argument. The messages may be hidden from your transcript because displaymsgmode is set to wlf.

See the [modelsim manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/131619-modelsim-user) on page 581 for more information.